# Some problems using JQCloud in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to pass hash from my controller to JS array but it can work. 
These are what I do:
 In controller:

```
@tag_cloud = []    
@tag_cloud[0] = {}
@tag_cloud[0]["text"]="Lorem"
@tag_cloud[0]["weight"]=15
.....
```

In view:

```
 var word_list =<%=@tag_cloud.to_json%>
 $(function() {
   $("#my_tag_cloud").jQCloud(word_list);
 });
```

I don't understand why json can't load to `word_list`

Comment: I think  last two questions are solved in my program.

Answer (score 1):

jQCloud works with downcase attributes. For example "text","link" , but not "Text","Link" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var word_list =<%= raw @tag_cloud.to_json%>
```

to prevent escaping quotes as `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find a minimal working rails version elsewhere:

I assume you have followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/archit/jqcloud-rails).

In order for the JQCloud rails gem to do its magic, a convenient format is an array of hashes. Normally we build this in the model to keep the controller slim, but for the sake of showing a minimal demo, you can put the following definition into a controller action:

```
@tag_cloud = [
   { text: "test", weight: 15},
   { text: "Ipsum", weight: 9, link: "http://jquery.com/"},
   { text: "Dolor", weight: 6, html: {title: "I can haz any html attribute"}},
   { text: "Sit", weight: 7},  {text: "Amet", weight: 5}
]
```

Now, in your corresponding view, add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var word_array =  <%= raw @tag_cloud.to_json %> ;
  $(function() {
    // When DOM is ready, select the container element and call
    // the jQCloud method, passing the array of words as the first argument.
    $("#example").jQCloud(word_array);
  });
</script>

<div id="example" style="width: 550px; height: 350px;"></div>
```

... and you should see the word cloud.